# SQL Server : Insert with Dynamic Queries just working when 1 Inserting Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, dynamic-sql

When trying to insert a value into a table coming from a dynamic SQL this is working perfectly.

```
INSERT TableName(ColumnName1) EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[History] ')
```

However, when I want to insert more than 1 value with this Dynamic SQL this is not working anymore.

```
INSERT TableName(ColumnName1, ColumnName2) EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[History] '), datum from kat.[dbo].[History] .
```

Is there a reason for this?

May thanks in advance,

Kat

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement, the dynamic SQL is returning a single, distinct result set, which is being inserted into your table. Your second statement, your treating it like it's a column, which it's not. Since you're pulling from the same table, you could either include `datum` inside your dynamic SQL, or join back out to `dbo.history` after the fact

Comment: Hi Xedni, Thanks for the answer. You mean to create the following : INSERT TableName(ColumnName1, ColumnName2) EXEC('SELECT '+@ColumnName+', datum from kat.[dbo].[History] ')

Comment: That was my thought, yes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. You are right, this is working, as both columns are in the same table. The problem comes when you want to combine different dynamic queries from different tables or constants, concats, etc...